# CPU usage is increasing

Tags: c#, performance

I am developing a windows service which gets data from sql server and send them to some other application in xml format.I have developed using .NET3.5.

The problem I am facing is when I run this process in Windows 7 operating system machine, CPU usage will be around 2% which is expected but when I run the same process on Widows server 2008 R2 VM machine the CPU usage is around 95%.

I have analyzed this process using process explorer and I found one difference in my server VM machine (windows 2008 R2) is my window service is using this thread "mscorwks.dll!CoUninitializeEE+0x18cf8". This thread is using more CPU. when I suspend this thread, my process CPU usage is around 2% and my process is working fine. In my dev machine (windows 7) I didnt see this thread. So I am thinking this is causing the issue.

Why this is happening in the server machine? How to solve this?

Computer properties showing these details: (both are 64 bit OS)

My dev machine configuration is: Intel Core i5 2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz 3.10GHz 
My server machine configuration is: Intel Xeon x5560 @ 2.80GHz 2.79GHz (2 Processors)

I have googled so much but I did not find any useful information.

Comment: It's always interesting to see some code...

Comment: I have no idea what causes this kind of issue. that's why I did not post any code. I have debugged my code and everything is working fine. This issue I am facing only in server machine

Comment: Is that all that the service does? How are you monitoring the files? Have you tried running the same program as a console app? What sort of file system are the files on (iSCSI NTFS?)? Are thereany differences in other processes, like virus sscanners?

Comment: @Aron sorry, my mistake. changed the windows service working description. please read the question again.

Comment: is your service hangs/stop or slows record transfer on server? how you are calculating sending speed? what is the issue?